# How to compare an audit file with the attribute in nifi

Tags: sql, json, text, apache-nifi, flowfile

I have an audit file like :

```
Abc,123
Code,234
```

where the first column is the filename and second column is the record count of the file.

Now I have 2 such flow files with its filename and respective count, which I need to compare it with this audit file.

So somehow I need to first merge all the filenames and respective counts as an attribute

Open the audit file, split it and compare with this attribute for each of the files

How can I do that in Nifi?

Comment: Add some more sample data, and also _specify_ the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.